# nodejs filter array in a multidimentional matrix

Tags: node.js, arrays, filter

Trying to retrieve the internal array (tags) from the following structure:
[image: Multidimensional array]

"tags" array contains the tag with "function" values, to get this I use the following expression:

```
let func = parsed.filter(x => x.tags.filter(x => x.tag == "function"));
```

being parsed the structure, but the result is:

[image: result]

It is including an array that doesn't contain "function" value in the "tag" property.
How can I get only the arrays that contain "function" values in the "tag" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the inner filter `x.tags.filter(x => x.tag == "function")` returns empty array `[]` which is truthy value even when it does not find any tag `function`.

You need to make sure to return true/false or at least correct truthy/falsy value.

Simple fix, just add `.length`:

```
let func = parsed.filter(x => x.tags.filter(x => x.tag == "function").length);
```

Zero `0` is falsy value and anything greater than `0` like `1` etc.
is truthy

**Test:**

```js
var arr = [
  { tags: [{ tag: 'function' }]},
  { tags: [{ tag: 'function2' }]}
].filter(x => x.tags.filter(x => x.tag == "function").length);
// arr is [{ tags: [{ tag: 'function' }]}]
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `let func = parsed.filter(x => x.tags.filter(x => x.tag == "function").length > 0);` is working, if you change your answer I can mark it as the one. Upvote if you liked the question ;)

Comment: @DanielV are you saying it doesn't work without the `> 0`? I tried it and it does work for me just fine without it. I added a snippet which you can test.

Comment: you are right it works!